# Is it right convention to put tabular view in the pop up

Tags: usability, gui-design, ux-designer

In our modal we need to showcase two options.To delete and edit the projects. Just wanna know if it is right convention to show tabular view in the pop up modal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is this, it is not a suitable way of approaching this two fold function.

Editing an item is an interaction which requires the user to change or add additional information, it is not destructive, and carries less weight than deleting a record.

Deleting information or a record is a destructive process which should be obvious to the user that nature of the action they are carrying out.

As such, I would retain the pop-over for an edit action and I would make the delete action pop-up contain any warning about deleting records that is appropriate to the item they are deleting.

These actions should be triggered separately from the page, so as not to confuse the user.

Answer (score 0):

I haven`t found anything against it neither in favor of it. For you specific example you might try to better illustrate the tabs are for now are confusing.

On the other side Edit & Delete as tabs is very confusing and unconventional. 
What happens on the Delete tab ?

Comment: yea tab naming is yet to decide. Just wanted to know about the tabular pop up modal. Thanks